# Por que no me deja reproducir un audio?

Tags: html, html5, vscode, google-chrome, audio

Estoy haciendo un programa de audio en visual studio con html5, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo no me deja reproducirlo, solo me salen los controles pero no puedo reproducir el tiempo de duración ni el boton de reproducción.

Aqui esta el código:

```html
  <audio controls >
      <source scr="mus/Five Nights at Freddy's 2 Song - The Living Tombstone (FNAF2).mp3"type="audio/mpeg">
     Su navegador no puede reproducir este audio

  </audio>
```

Comment: Intenta dejar un espacio entre `.mp3"type="a`... es decir, antes del `type`.

Comment: No reproducirá porque el audio es `.mp3` yel typo es `mpeg`. Cambia el tipo a `type/mp3`

Comment: O simplemente se puede eliminar el atributo `type="" `

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita información adicional porque con los datos de la publicación, podría ser por muchos motivos diferentes: la ruta al fichero es incorrecta, el archivo de sonido es de un formato no soportado, el fichero está corrupto... Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir aclaraciones. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio.)

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a stackoverflow, primero que nada debes colocar el source (src) dentro de la etiqueta inicial de audio y no afuera tal cual el ejemplo que coloque abajo `<audio controls id="mireproductor" src="./By_Me.mp3"></audio>`  y segundo, probar con un nombre de archivo sencillo y sin espacio, para saber si lo escribiste bien o no, hoy en dia los navegadores no tienen problemas con los espacios en blanco pero veo que el nombre es muy largo y posiblemente exista un problema de que no se encuentra el archivo y por ende no se puede reproducir.

Aqui te traigo un ejemplo con algunos botones que controlan la reproduccion y que te pueden ayudar en la funcionalidad:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Player Audio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls id="mireproductor" src="./By_Me.mp3"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').play()">Reproducir</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').pause()">Pausa</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').load()">Parar</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').volume += .1">Subir volumen</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('mireproductor').volume -= .1">Bajar volumen</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

IMPORTANTE: Tomalo como ejemplo para que veas todo lo que puedes hacer, sin embargo para un mejor codigo deberias crear las funciones javascript en un archivo aparte y no dentro del onclick, lo hice asi para que sea mas facil de visualizar lo que te quiero explicar.